# Append lines of text above or below the dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame (dimension:600000 X 6). All 6 columns are integer values representing different features for each row. I would like to add three lines of text either above or below the data frame which are common to all the rows. Is it possible to insert some lines of text below or above the data frame?

For example:
Given a dataframe,

```
    name<-letters[1:10]
    length<-c(140,50,25,120,156,146,180,98,120,110)
    quality<-c(20,25,35,20,15,28,32,35,29,25)
    df<-data.frame(name,length,quality)
```

how to insert three lines of text either above or below the data frame,df:

```
    No. of reads = 10
    %AT=32
    %GC=30
```

The output should look like:

```
      name length quality
   1     a    140      20
   2     b     50      25
   3     c     25      35
   4     d    120      20
   5     e    156      15
   6     f    146      28
   7     g    180      32
   8     h     98      35
   9     i    120      29
   10    j    110      25
   No. of reads = 10
   %AT=32
   %GC=30
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear of what you're looking for? Show an example of the output that you want

Comment: By "output", do you mean the data stored in an object, or the contents of a (text) file you're writing to?  If the former, I recommend `mydata <- list(df=df, meta=[your lines of text])` ; if the latter, take a look at `write.table` with `append=TRUE` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
prettyprint <- function() {
  print(df)
  cat("No. of reads = 10",
      "\n%AT=32",
      "\n%GC=30")
 }
 prettyprint()
```

The output looks something like this:

```
   name length quality
1     a    140      20
2     b     50      25
3     c     25      35
4     d    120      20
5     e    156      15
6     f    146      28
7     g    180      32
8     h     98      35
9     i    120      29
10    j    110      25
No. of reads = 10 
%AT=32 
%GC=30
```

Comment: if you don't want to print, you can use `comment(df)<-c("No. of reads = 10","n%AT=32","n%GC=30")`

Comment: The output of `comment(df)` is `[1] "No. of reads = 10" "\n%AT=32"          "\n%GC=30"` though, which isn't formatted like Ram wants.

Comment: How would you actually save that text to the dataframe?